# link existing account to facebook - problems/questions

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website that have facebook connection and classic user_name/password login. The system currently works if user clicks facebook_connect button. However, I want to link existing account to facebook because user can choose to login with his/her user_name, password credentials and also want to make facebook auto-connected after clicking facebook connect button. I have a field namely `fb_connect` (1 or 0) that holds if user uses facebook connect or not. So, the scenario is the following ;

1) I chosed to register with facebook connect. I clicked facebook connect button and got `$user` field. My website make a registration process, gets facebook email, generates a   password and sends login credentials to the email address to make user also login with email/password.

2) When I got the email, I say : "Well, it looks ok, let me try with these login credentials( email/password) and check if the website already linked the account with these credentials"

3) I enter the website and used normal login. (PROBLEM 1 OCCURS HERE) My website checks if `fb_connect` is 1 or 0. if it's 1 then, my website calls `FB.login` function in the javascript sdk of facebook.

PROBLEM 1 : If users have existing account and use classic login, I don't want users to see an empty dialog flashes for 1-2 seconds after each login to the system.

PROBLEM 2 : When I open private browsing in chrome or mozilla and use classic login like in the problem 1's case, facebook popup wants facebook user_name and password to login. But, I certainly don't want that.

I looked at twitter and opened a private tab. After logging in to twitter and check if facebook is linked or not, twitter says my existing account is linked. I say "How's that happened ? Twitter doesn't make me enter login credentials for facebook ??? "

I think I'm doing something wrong. I really need help. I'm using php. Some logical statements, algorithms and code is needed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I looked at twitter and opened a private tab. After logging in to twitter and check if facebook is linked or not, twitter says my existing account is linked. I say "How's that happened ? Twitter doesn't make me enter login credentials for facebook ??? "

Only logical explanation IHMO: You have already connected your twitter with your Facebook account in the past, and they just look that info up in their database, without actually querying any data from Facebook at this point.

> PROBLEM 1 : If users have existing account and use classic login, I don't want users to see an empty dialog flashes for 1-2 seconds after each login to the system.

Well than save that info, that they had their account even before they connected it with Facebook, resp. did not *create* it using Facebook, in your database as well.

> PROBLEM 2 : When I open private browsing in chrome or mozilla and use classic login like in the problem 1's case, facebook popup wants facebook user_name and password to login. But, I certainly don't want that.

Then **don’t** use private browsing. There is no way of *not* being asked to log into Facebook, if you use FB.login and Facebook has no way of telling if the user is already logged in to Facebook.

Comment: So, you say that twitter get facebook connect data from their own database. Then, how could they handle auto facebook post after tweeting ?

Comment: Maybe they are still using offline_access, or maybe (more likely) they just get a new access token every time a user connected to their app visits their site in the background.

Comment: Moreover, in problem 1, you suggested to save it on my database. But, I need to be able to auto publish actions according to user actions in my website. To do that, `$facebook` object should be created. So, in private browsing, it is impossible to publish actions.

Comment: I also just checked twitter auto-post to facebook in private browsing. it works.